# Function from angular js controlles is not executing when testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am testing my angularjs application with Jasmine and Karma.

My test looks like this:

```
describe('Login test', function() {
  // Mock our module in our tests
  beforeEach(module('Project'));

  var ctrl, scope;
  // inject the $controller and $rootScope services
  // in the beforeEach block
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('loginController', {
        $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should get login success',function() {
    scope.loginClick('user', 'pass');
  });
});
```

I have a login controller with the loginClick function, and inside this function i have another function which is making a POST request. The problem is that the inner function is never executed, i try to console.log() to see if the function is called but with no success.
My function looks like this:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', function ($scope, $http, $route) {
  console.log('controller call'); // yes it works
  ...
  $scope.loginClick = function (username, password) {
    console.log('controller call'); // yes it works

    handler.reqPOST('/login', userData, function (result) {
      console.log('login request'); // no output is sent to the console
    });
 };
}]);
```

The handler object is include in the karma configuration file at start-up.

Comment: If reqPOST is making http request you need to setup mock http backend using $httpBackend service in ngMock.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you have very good reason, `$http` is the way to go in angularJS to call the back-end, it also makes it more testable.

In any case you should mock the post call, in a unit-test you don't want to rely on the back-end

In your case, you could use a spy (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies):

```
describe('Login test', function(){

  beforeEach(module('Project'));      

  var ctrl, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('loginController', {
      $scope: scope,
    });
  }));

  it('test login', function () {

    spyOn(handler, 'reqPOST');

    scope.loginClick('user', 'pass');

    expect(handler.reqPOST).toHaveBeenCalledWith('user', 'pass');
  });
});
```

Comment: `spyOn` is creating a mock of `handler` so the post call is mocked in this example.

Comment: expect(handler.reqPOST).toHaveBeenCalled(); - this test passes, but the problem is that the actual POST request is never sent

Comment: The whole point of mocking is that you replace the backend request by a fake request that is predictable, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object